If I bought an Asus Expertbook i5 with LInux ubuntu 12.0.4, I could update it to the last version fo LInux ubuntu
If I bought an Asus expertbook computer with I5 24gb with Linux Ubuntu 12.0.4, I could update it to Linux version such as 24.04.1 LTS, no matter the method, so I should bought, or the S.O is very old and I couldn't update it.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 12.04 or the 2012-April release had two upgrade paths; both of which are now gone due to End of Life or End of Standard Support and are thus off-topic here. Update procedures are now difficult, so a re-install makes far more sense.
